# CakePHP field not updating

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am having a very strange problem. I am doing a standard saving in cakephp from a form, nothing crazy at all:

```
$this->Ride->read(null,$id);
$ride = $this->Ride->data;

$this->Ride->set(array(
                'assigned' => 2,
                'pickup_driver_id' => $driver['UserDriver']['id']
            ));

$this->Ride->save()
```

However, everytime ALL fields update EXCEPT the assigned field. Assigned is tinyint(2) in the DB. I've tried not validating...etc. Any suggestions would be great! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you double check your model definition to see if there is anything funny going on there.  Turning off validation was going to be my first suggestion but you say you have covered that so I won't say anything about that. (grin)

Also, check the returned value of the $this->Ride->save() method, it should be true.  If not, check for errors like this...

```
if(!$this->Ride->save()){
    debug($this->Ride->validationErrors); die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes i did try validation errors. The strange part is, $this->Ride->save() succeeds fine, ALL fields are updated except assigned in the database. pickup_driver_id is in-fact the new value, as well as other fields that are set, all except assigned...

Comment: Turnes out CakePHP treats tinyint(1) as a virtual boolean and will only save 0 or 1 to that field. I changed it to tinyint(2) but did NOT clear the app/tmp/models cache so it was still not working until i changed that. Found it here:
http://www.devarticles.in/cakephp/field-type-tinyint1-would-not-save-values-other-than-0-and-1-in-cakephp/